# Where does the Cuddlefish go if you tell it to stop following you?

Tags: subnautica

I'm playing Subnautica, and I was wondering where my Cuddlefish goes when I ask it to stop following me.

Answer (score 1):

**They stay around the spot you told them to stop following you.** They might swim around a little, though, and they're easy to miss.

This is vaguely written on the [Cuddlefish page](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Cuddlefish#Behavior) of the Subnautica Fandom website:

> "*The Cuddlefish will either follow the player around or stay in one area when told to. The player can tell it to stop/start following them using <kbd>RMB</kbd>.*"